# TensorFlow 2 documentation for graph-mode

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

When I check the TensorFlow documentation ([Python API docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/) or [guides](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide)), it all seems exclusively for eager-mode. Almost all the examples don't even mention this.
For some specific operation/function like `tf.nn.relu`, this does not really make any difference.
However, for more complex things like `tf.data` ([`Dataset` API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset), [`guide`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data)), it likely makes a difference. Esp all the examples would be different for graph mode.

Where can I find recent documentation (API references, guides, tutorials, examples) for graph mode?
(My current fallback is to check latest TF 1 documentation. But at some point, this will become more and more outdated.)

Or is graph mode deprecated so far that documentation for it seems not necessary anymore?

Answer (score 2):

Graph mode in TensorFlow 2 is different from graph mode in TensorFlow 1. Instead of using sessions and placeholders, TensorFlow 2 uses functions annotated with [tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function). The eager mode examples you see can be executed in graph mode by wrapping them within a `tf.function`.

If you prefer to use the TensorFlow 1 style of graph mode with sessions and placeholders, you can still do so in TensorFlow 2 by using the [tf.compat.v1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1) module. The API docs in that module describe the TensorFlow 1 style of graph mode. You can find archived guides about TensorFlow 1 graph mode at https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/master/site/en/r1/guide

Comment: Thanks. But how can graph-mode examples be executed then in TF2? Where can I read about that? Or for graph-mode in TF2, you have to use `tf.compat.v1`? About graph mode in TF2, you are basically saying there is no updated guide documentation anymore, and I should check the old TF1 guides? (There are only the automatically generated API docs for `tf.compat.v1` and all submodules.)

Comment: In TF2, graph code looks the same as eager code (but it's inside a @tf.function), so you don't need separate documentation for using graph mode. This guide talks about using tf.function to make eager code more performant (by using graph mode): https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function